# Storage of multiple (~10000) SVG fill patterns

Tags: d3.js, svg, fill

I am converting a web service from plain HTML/ASP.NET to D3/ASP.NET. I need about 10000 different constant fill patterns with about 50 different ones (from the 10000) on a single web page depending on user requests. With HTML, all these patterns were small 20x20px png files in a directory and were only loaded by filename when requested by the page. With D3, I could make a huge 'defs' file with 10000 SVG 'patterns' but it would require to be loaded every time. Any suggestions on how to store these patterns efficiently ? Thanks.
Jacques

Comment: Are the groups of 50 patterns logically grouped, so they could be put in separate files? Or are they ad-hoc so you don't know ahead of time which will be required?

Comment: generate the pattern on demand

Comment: The database stores ~250000 items grouped in ~10000 classes (one pattern for each class). The requested page shows symbolic maps of hundreds of items which classes can be identified using the patterns. These patterns cannot be generated on demand because they need to be consistent between requests and between users.These are genetic maps of different organisms and gene conservation is assessed using the patterns.

Comment: load them on demand via ajax then.